# ESP8266[NodeMCU] LittleFS Library Problem

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu, spiffs

I'm working on Arduino IDE to implement LittleFS file system.However I get the error message as **"src\LITTLEFS.cpp:17:21: fatal error: vfs_api.h: No such file or directory
#include "vfs_api.h"** when I try to compile my program.

Code :

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "FS.h"
#include <LITTLEFS.h>

#define FORMAT_LITTLEFS_IF_FAILED true

void setup(){
  
}
void loop(){
  
}
```

Arduino version : 1.8.13

Board : NodeMCU v3(ESP12-E Module 1.0)

Flash Size : 4MB(1 MB SPIFFS)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you've chosen the [ESP32 version](https://github.com/lorol/LITTLEFS) of this project, which doesn't run on ESP8266. Try the [ESP8266 version](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/LittleFS) instead.

Comment: Tkanks a lot Tarmo , problem was about the version of ESP8266 library(2.5.0). If new version (2.7.4) is used then the problem will be solved.